# Rejection region: the probability udner true parameter

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

I would like to understand in the third snippet below in the context of statistical hypotheses testing how was obtained the formula (namely the numbers $1-,22.5$ and $-3\theta$) in the example 8.2.3 originated from the example 8.2.1:

$$Q(\theta)=1-\Psi(22.5-3\theta)$$

[Book extract 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zl6xW.jpg)

[Book extract 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9YjB.jpg)

[Book extract 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qk2Gn.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually says $Q(\theta)=1-\Phi(22.5-3\theta)$ where $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution function of a standard normal distribution.

Here the underlying population is $\mathcal N(\theta, 1)$ so the average of a sample size $9$ has mean $\theta$ and standard deviation $1/3$.

So the probability the sample average is less than $7.5$ is $\Phi\left(\dfrac{7.5 - \theta}{1/3}\right) = \Phi\left({22.5 - 3\theta}\right)$

and the probability the sample average is greater than $7.5$ is $1-\Phi(22.5 - 3\theta)$.

This is the power of a test that rejects $H_0$ iff $\bar X > 7.5$

Comment: I understand everything in your answer but for this: "So the probability the sample average is less than 7.5 is $$\Psi(\frac{7.5−\theta}{1/3})=\Psi(22.5−3\theta)$$". Please note that I'm a beginner to c.d.f. Can you please give me a hint for this ?

Comment: @user852508 If $Y \sim \mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then $\mathbb P(Y \le y)=\Phi\left(\frac{y-\mu}{\sigma}\right)$.  Phi not Psi

Comment: And how would the formula for $\Phi$ changed if we had $n=9$ samples with ${\cal N}(\theta,\sigma^2)$ instead of ${\cal N}(\theta,1)$ ? Can you give me a page in Nitis Mukhopadyay's book ?

Comment: @user852508 - No - I do not have the book.  You could say that $\mathbb P(\bar X>7.5)=1-\Phi\left(\frac{7.5-\theta}{\sqrt{\sigma^2/9}}\right)$ but really you are straying into the realm of Student $t$-tests

Comment: Please, how have you derived $1/3$ from $n=9$: why is it $\frac{1}{\sqrt(9)}$ ?

Comment: If you have $n$ i.i.d random variables each with variance $\sigma^2$ then their sum has variance $n\sigma^2$ while their average has variance $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$ and standard deviation $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt n}$